# how to set application theme in code rather than in manifest

Tags: android, kotlin

I want my application to apply Leanback-theme on Android-TV, and AppCompat-theme on Android phones.

originally manifest.xml

```
<application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/tv"
            android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        >
```

Now manifest.xml

```
<application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        >
```

I have tried several versions listed below, but none of them work. All of these gives a white background.

styles.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="tv" parent="@style/Theme.Leanback"/>
    <style name="phone" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat"/>
</resources>
```

MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : Activity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        application.setTheme(R.style.tv)
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        showLayout()
    }

    private fun showLayout() {
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_tv)
    }
}
```

MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : Activity() {
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            showLayout()
        }

        private fun showLayout() {
            application.setTheme(R.style.tv)
            setContentView(R.layout.layout_tv)
    }
}
```

MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : Activity() {
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            showLayout()
        }

        private fun showLayout() {
            val theme = super.getTheme()
            theme.applyStyle(R.style.tv, true)

            setContentView(R.layout.layout_tv)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When setting a theme programmatically, two things must be taken into account:

1. The theme must be set **before** calling super.onCreate
2. The theme must be set **per activity** and using the **activity context**

So out of the three versions you tried, the first one is the most adequate, but you need to call setTheme with the activity context, not the application context.

In other words, call it like this:

```
setTheme(R.style.tv)
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
```